# importing php inside the Yii using URL management

Tags: php, yii, bootstrapping

I have implementing project in Yii. i importing external php file inside the Yii using Yii URL management. its not importing properly. I added my code following please suggest me where i did mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(course) {

$.post("  <?php Yii::app()->baseUrl.'script/rpc.php'?>;{queryString: ""+course+""}, 
            function(data){
                if(data.length >2) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#course').show();
                }
            });
</script>
```

Comment: this line only error: $.post("  <?php Yii::app()->baseUrl.'script/rpc.php'?>; please tell me how to call baseUrl

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the output.

Change

```
<?php Yii::app()->baseUrl.'script/rpc.php'; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'script/rpc.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What result are you getting? You also need to take out the trailing semicolon (;) after the php closure. That should be a comma not a semicolon. See: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: am calling like this   $.post(<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'script/rpc.php'; ?>, {queryString: ""+course+""},

Comment: my search function could be works. ie auto complete function calling from the external php file which is script/rpc.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(course) {

$.post(<?php Yii::app()->baseUrl.'script/rpc.php'; ?>, {queryString: ""+course+""}, 
            function(data){
                if(data.length >2) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#course').show();
                }
            });
            }
</script>
```